# Copy input values in option dropdown jquery

Tags: jquery

How to duplicate input value into dropdown option automatically?

I have text field where user will going to input some values (Let say an amount), Now, I want this values to be copied or duplicate in my dropdown option field automatically, particularly on my first "option", How do I do that?

```
<input id='appraisal_value' type='number'>

<select id='srp'>
    <option value='//This is where the users values from input `appraisal_value` goes '>Appraisal Value</option>
    <option value'<?php echo $BookValue; ?>'>Book Value</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#appraisal_value').change(function() {

  var value = $(this).val();
  $('#srp').prepend('<option>'+value +'</option>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='appraisal_value' type='number'>

<select id='srp'>
  <option value='//This is where the users values from input `appraisal_value` goes '>Appraisal Value</option>

</select>
```

Use [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

> Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the beginning of each element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: Thank you. Worked like beast!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#appraisal_value").on("keyup", function(){
  $("#srp").children("option:first").val($(this).val());
});
```

This example shows when user keyup in the text field, value of first option in the select will replace with text field value.